# amCharts4: Date axis grid not showing every month

Tags: typescript, amcharts4

I'm not being able to specify where the grid lines should go for my date axis in amCharts 4. Here is my code:

```
let dateAxis = this.chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.dataFields.date="submittedDtm";
dateAxis.gridIntervals.setAll([
    { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 },
]);
```

As you can see I'm trying to make the chart have a grid line for every month. But instead, I only get grid lines for April, July, October, and next January:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3ZGj.png)

This is for the data points "2023-04-05 14:48:00"
and "2023-12-05 14:46:00".

In addition, my gridIntervals seems to cause my data to group into months, even though as I understand it, that's only supposed to happen if I set `dateAxis.groupData = true;` and set the appropriate `dateAxis.groupIntervals`.

I've tried many things such as `dateAxis.groupData = true;` and `dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;`. Currently I don't have `dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance` set to anything, but I've tried different values for that and it didn't work either.

EDIT: Resolved. This was an issue with data granularity. Even though my data is given with accuracy to the second, since I only gave a small number of data points, amcharts thought my granularity was much larger. When I set my base interval with

```html
dateAxis.baseInterval = {
            "timeUnit": "second",
            "count": 1
}
```

it now works correctly.